# Choosing the Lucene/Elastic Search highlighter in C# NEST

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, highlighting, nest

I haven't found where or whether this property is exposed in C# NEST. For example, in elastic search you can specify the plain highlighter as follows:

```
 {
  "size": 500,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\"C S M\"",
      "fields": [
        "contentsStem"
      ],
      "default_operator": "and"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<em>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</em>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "contentsStem": { "type" : "plain" }
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "nameStem"
  ]
}
```

Notice type:plain is specified as a property of contesntsStem. In NEST, I have the following code:

```
        if (this.HighlightFields.Any())
        {
            var highlightFieldsAugmented = this.HighlightFields.Select(f => UnanalyzedFields.Contains(f) ? f : f + this.AnalyzerMode).ToList();

            var highlightFieldsActions = highlightFieldsAugmented
                .Select(field => new Action<HighlightFieldDescriptor<ElasticSearchHit>>(descriptor => descriptor.OnField(field)))
                .ToArray();

            searchdescriptor.Highlight(h => h.PreTags(this.HighlightPretag)
                .PostTags(this.HighlightPosttag)
                .OnFields(highlightFieldsActions)
                );
        }

 var hits = ElasticSearchEngine.ElasticClientSingleInstance.Search(searchdescriptor);
```

This code uses the FV highlighter by default but I haven't found the way to change it to the plain highlighter. Is there any way to use the plain highlighter in this case form NEST in C#?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is unmapped in NEST 0.12.0 the upcomming 1.0 version will allow you to do:

```
var highlightFieldsActions = highlightFieldsAugmented
    .Select(field => new Action<HighlightFieldDescriptor<ElasticSearchHit>>(
        descriptor => descriptor
            .OnField(field)
            .Type("plain")
        )
    )
    .ToArray();
```